# How can initialize Morris.JS line chart with a selected point?

Tags: javascript, morris.js

How can I set the selected point always active when I create the chart:
[image: set the selected point always active]

Comment: When you set *active*, you mean with both zooming and tooltip or just zooming?

Comment: i mean the both zooming and tooltip